# how to get image´s path with onclick and save it in a variable

Tags: javascript, events

here is my html:

```
<form action="submitPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="savePathInVar();"> 
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="' . $id . '" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" onclick="changecolor();" /></td>
    <td><img id="' . $id . '" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" onclick="changecolor();" /></td>
  </tr>
    <input type="hidden" value="ClickedImaged" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />          
  </table>
</form>
```

Now i need a function `changeColor()` to highlight the one clicked image..
and the function `savePathInVar()` to save the clicked image´s path in the input-hidden-field.
Anyone who can help me?
ps: this is where `$id` comes from:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    // get all the product details
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
         $id = $row["id"];
         $id = "img.$id";
                     blabla...
```

would be really nice if anyone could help me.. i am quite new to javascript :)

---

**This was added to the answer by OP. It belongs to the question**

**EDIT:**

Am I doing someone's homework

UPDATE 3, my whole code:

```
<script>
function changecolor(img)
{
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0,j=images.length; i<j; i++)
{
    images[i].style.borderColor="#000";
}
img.style.borderColor="#F00";
//Operate on img location as before
savePathInVar(img.src);
}
function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
var form = document.createElement("form");
var inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.name="imgSrc";
inp.value=ImgLocation;
form.appendChild(inp);
form.method="post";
form.submit();//this will refresh the page
}
</script>

<form name="form_name" action="submitPage.php" method="POST" onsubmit="savePathInVar();">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</table>
</form>
```

And my submitPage.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set ('display_errors' , 1);
$imgSrc = $_POST['imgSrc'];
echo $imgSrc;
?>
```

when i mark an image and click "submit", i get:

> Notice: Undefined index: imgSrc in /srv/disk8/1391019/www/myfirststore.eu.pn/submitPage.php on line 5

what do i have to do ?? greetings and thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, change `' . $id . '` to `<?php echo $id ?>`

Comment: thanks totally forgotten..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onclick="changecolor();"` to `onclick="changecolor(this);"`

```
function changecolor(img)
{
    savePathInVar(img.src);
}
function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    //Do what you want with ImgLocation

}
```

**UPDATE**

To unhighlight all images but one img:

```
function changecolor(img)
{
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0,j=images.length; i<j; i++)
    {
        images[i].style.borderColor="#000";
    }
    img.style.borderColor="#F00";
    //Operate on img location as before
    savePathInVar(img.src);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

To submit the image src to php, create a form and post it:

```
function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.name="imgSrc";
    inp.value=ImgLocation;
    form.appendChild(inp);
    form.method="post";
    form.submit();//this will refresh the page
}
```

In php:

```
$imgSrc = $_POST['imgSrc'];
```

Comment: Good answer, +1! Just to be clear, you might want to state that it is in the onclick attribute that changecolor(this) should be placed.

Comment: ok thanks, for "function changeColor()": how do i get those element(images) highlighted by clicking at them? (only one should be marked/ others should be unmarked than )

Comment: Do you want to unhighlight all images inside the table? or row? or column? and to highlight them, im not sure which method you would prefer. You could style the background-color of `td` with #F00 and change the `img.style.opacity`

Comment: if one specific image inside the table is clicked, only this specific image should be highlighted e.g. change border color. if one image is highlighted, any other image should be unhighlighted. do you know how to solve this? greetings

Comment: I wont solve it for you, but here is a tip: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`

Comment: but i didnt give any tag like:  name="img"

Comment: so do i have to include? :  [CODE] name="img" [/CODE]

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` is different to `document.getElementsByTagName` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: `highlightedImage = 0; 
    function unHighlightAll()
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName(img).style.borderColor = "#000000";
}
function changecolor(img)
{
    unHighlightAll();
    // How do i highlight the clicked image now?
    savePathInVar(img.src);
}
function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    //  How do i put save the path of the clicked img in a variable and put it in the input-hidden-field?

}`

Comment: ok and how to save the "path" of the highlighted image in a variable?         `function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    var NewVariable = savePathInVar(ImgLocation) // ?? //How do i save ImgLocation in a variable now?
}`

Comment: `ImgLocation` is a variable

Comment: ok and how can i output the path of the clicked image in my submitPage.php?